# JQuery Mobile HREF link not working with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a button that I want to open a panel.  Unfortunately my javascript is getting in the way.  It's a notifications center in the panel and in order to retrieve the notifications I have to put javascript in the href of the link....but its not opening the open.

I put tags where the problem is that say THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES.

If I change the href to #myContent then it will open, but in order for the script to work I need to to be javascript in the href.

Here's my code:

```
<?  //PHP for getting username and database here ?>
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
    });
}
</script>



<!-- BEGIN PAGE 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="feed" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="panel" id="settingspanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
    <!--THIS IS THE LEFT PANEL-->

    </div>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="padding-top: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <a href="#settingspanel" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-reorder icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
        <center><img src="images/logo_app_white.png" height="25px"></center>

            <!--THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES-->
        <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-bell-alt icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-right: 20px;"></a><? echo $number; ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   


    <!--This is where the content of the page goes-->


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="border-top: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-top: 5px;">
        <div data-role="navbar" style="background: #ce8339;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#feed" class="icon-tasks icon-2x" data-ajax="false">My Feed</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submit" class="icon-upload icon-2x" data-ajax="false">Submit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#browse" class="icon-search icon-2x" data-ajax="false">Browse</a></li>
                <li><a href="myprojects.php" class="icon-folder-open-alt icon-2x" data-ajax="false">Projects</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <!-- /navbar -->    
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="myContent" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">

    <!--THIS IS THE PANEL-->
    </div>


</div>

<!-- END PAGE 1 -->
```

Why isn't the panel opening and how can I fix the issue.

Comment: Why put javascript in the `href` tag and not in `onclick`. my guess is `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleDiv('myContent')">` will fix the issue.

Comment: Please put your comment in an answer so I can mark it.  don't forget to add a ; at the end of the onclick command though!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why put javascript in the 'href' tag and not in 'onclick'? 
My guess is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleDiv('myContent');">
```

will fix the issue.